# How to store hierarchial data and display it in a table

Tags: perl

I want to store hierarchial data like:

```
d1 -> {  

       ns1  -> {ip1,ip2},
       ns2 -> {ip3,ip4},
       ....
       ....
      },
d2 ->  {  

       ns3  -> {ip3,ip5},
       ns4 -> {ip6,ip9},
       ....
       ....
  },
```

and so on.....

I know I need to use references, but I am having hard time understanding it.
Can anyone give me a head start ?
After storing like above, I need to display them in a table with d1 , ns and ip as columns

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your syntax is all messed up. Refer to [perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html) and [perldsc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html).

I've rearranged it to a hash whose values are a few hash references, whose values are a few array references:

```
%hash = (
    d1 => {
        ns1 => [ip1,ip2],
        ns2 => [ip3,ip4],
        ....
        ....
    },
    d2 => {
        ns3 => [ip3,ip5],
        ns4 => [ip6,ip9],
        ....
        ....
    },
);
```

Hopefully that's a start.